# Define a scope for javascript Function constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor, scope

I'm trying to create some dynamic functions that require an enclosing scope.  Currently this works:

```
eval("with (scope) (function () {return scope.prop})")
```

This approach seems a bit hacky.  User supplied code is nowhere near this so I'm not worried about security, it's just that it seems like there should be a better way.

I know the `Function` constructor does not include anything apart from the global scope, but I was hoping there was some way to 'inject' scope into the `Function` constructor.  Not call or apply or bind, but construct a function with a defined scope.

Is it possible to define a scope when using the `Function` constructor?  Is it something that may be included in the standard in the future?

Comment: What you're describing is incredibly bad practice. Can you please describe the problem a bit more, so that we can suggest the correct way to do what you want?

Comment: If there is no user supplied code, can't this just be a function that returns something based on it's parameters?

Comment: Executing the function created from the `Function` constructor will have its own scope before the global. You can also define function parameters, so if you wanted to pass a `scope` object (or any other data) for the resulting function's code to use, you can do that.

Comment: The functions are going to be used as getters (Object.defineProperty).  The reason I need the scope is that the function bodies are actually from external scripts that have no idea about the scope they're in.  In fact, the scripts will be evaluated in a sandboxed JS interpreter (in browser) that has no access to any scope or browser API.