# Specify object to use as global scope in new Function constructor?

Tags: javascript, function, scope, global

Is there a way in Javascript to specify an object to use as the global scope when creating a function using `new Function(...)`?

For instance, consider a string

```
  var str = "return foo()";  // user supplied, generated by a trusted program
```

we can create a function with this string, passing in certain arguments

```
  var fn = new Function(str);
  var result = fn()
```

This works if `foo` is defined in the global scope, either `window` in a browser or `GLOBAL.global` in Node.js.

But is there a way to give this newly created function an object, e.g. `{foo: function() { return 42; }}` and tell it to use that as the global scope?

The motivation here is the universe of possible functions that might be assumed to exist on the global scope is unknown. I'd like to define an object using ES6 `Proxy` that provides default implementations to unanticipated functions, and pass that object in to be used as the global scope within the function.

I know it's possible to explicitly define and pass in specific arguments, e.g.

```
  var fn = new Function("foo", str);
  var result = fn(function() { return "bar"; })
```

but that won't work as i'd like to handle methods we didn't anticipate.

It's also possible to pass in an object, e.g.

```
 var scope = { foo: function() { return 42; }
 var fn = new Function("scope", str);
 var result = fn(scope)
```

but that won't work as the string says `"return foo()"` not `"return scope.foo()"`

[Define a scope for javascript Function constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41475260/define-a-scope-for-javascript-function-constructor)

**EDIT**

Answer suggested from comments by @ChiragRavindra and @RobG...

```
 var str = "return 'sand'+foo(); "  
 var o = {foo: function() { return "bar"}}
 var fn = new Function("obj", "with (obj) { " + str + "}")
 fn = fn.bind(o,o)
 fn(str) //==> "sandbar"
```

Comment: [With](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) or [Bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) may help?

Comment: You seem to want to define a global **object**, not global "scope". That doesn't seem possible. *with* will put your "scope" object at the start of the scope chain whereas you wan it at the end. *bind* sets the value of *this*, which is not related to identifier resolution on the scope chain, i.e. it has nothing to do with scope. These issues are usually addressed using the module pattern or immediately invoked function expressions (IIFEs).

Comment: aha!   `with` is the idea I was searching for.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can. Define a `Proxy` that resolves every property with a function. So, to implement your second example, we can do this:

```js
function factory (string) {
  const callable = new Function(`with(this){${string}}`);

  return function fn (method) {
    return callable.call(new Proxy({}, {
      has () { return true; },
      get (target, key) { if (typeof key !== 'symbol') return method; }
    }));
  };
}

const fn = factory('return foo()');
const result = fn(() => 42);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This example is a gem, really elegant.

Comment: @prototype while your sentiment is appreciated, I must strongly disagree. I would not refer to any implementation containing a `Function` constructor or `with` statement, or even a `Proxy` for that matter, as "elegant". I would use a word like "intriguing", or "nifty", but I would definitely be concerned if I saw this technique in production code anywhere.

Comment: Proxies are dead slow, however, as it involves bouncing through Javascript for every global name access; and `with` merely layers a new scope over the top of the existing one. Making `has` return true prevents most accesses hitting the real global scope but may have nasty knock-on effects due to upsetting Javascript semantics. Also it's not recursive, so creating new functions will always use the real global scope. (I'm trying to solve exactly the same problem as the poster.)

Comment: Incidentally, as a crude performance hack; create a new object (which is your new global scope) whose prototype is the proxy above; then use _that_ as the `with` expression. The proxy will only be invoked for properties which aren't in your replacement context object, which is probably not any of the ones where performance is an issue.

Comment: @DavidGiven I certainly hope you don't intend to use this in production somewhere. When you say things like suggesting a performance improvement, it sounds like you do. Please keep in mind I do not endorse this as a production-worthy solution and the general answer should be "no don't do that, refactor your code instead so that you don't _have_ unresolved references to deal with."